# Any data structure to define bucket for Hashing

Tags: java, data-structures

Do we have any data structure available other than `Array` to use it as bucket in hashing algorithm used for implementing [HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) 
Fixed length of `Array` requires to do re-hashing (transfer elements to new capacity bucket once reached the threshold).

Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before talking about alternatives, let's talk about some of the reasons why folks like using arrays as the bucket structure:

- **It supports extremely fast random access.** Once you have the hash code, you can index into the slot you'd like in time O(1), with a very low hidden constant factor.
- **Insertions are amortized-constant time.** As you've mentioned, you do need to periodically grow the array, but the cost of inserting another element is *amortized* constant because you have to do O(n) insertions before you trigger an O(n)-cost resize.

If you swap out an array for another data structure, you are likely going to have to pay some kind of extra cost in the course of doing so.

One approach that doesn't use a top-level table is [extendible hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing), which works by using a trie as its bucket structure. The hash code is treated as a number in some base (say, base two) and the elements are found by walking a trie for some number of bits or digits to find the object you're looking for. When the buckets get too full, they're split, which does require shuffling some things around, but that amount can be controlled. The drawback of this approach is that lookups are slower. For starters, you have to follow a number of pointers in order to get to your final element, which often has poor locality of reference. Second, if your hash codes are long (say, they have k bits in them), the cost of a lookup becomes O(k) rather than O(1). For large k (say, an 128-bit hash), this can take quite a long time.